# iOS 11 - Display large title on UINavigationBar without using UINavigationController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I have `UIViewController` with `UINavigationBar` as a subview. No `UINavigationController` is involved.

I'm trying to display large titles. As the [docs directed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/2908999-preferslargetitles) us to do:

```
myCustomNavigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
myCustomNavigationItem.largeTitleDisplayMode = .always
```

But it remains at the previous display mode (iOS 10 navigation mode).

When trying the same code with `UINavigationController` it works as expected. Is it not possible without `UINavigationController` or am I not approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know exactly at what point in the view life cycle you are including those lines of code, but if you execute them within the `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` method it works perfectly.
I have checked it on Xcode 9 GM.

EDIT: I'm sorry I did not read that you're not using a `UINavigationController`. An `UINavigationBar` without an `UINavigationController` have no sense. Please, add your `UIViewController` to an `UINavigationController` and you'll see the changes you want if you put those lines under `viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool)` method

:)

Comment: Altho there is a good a mount of reasons why not always use UINavigationController. I took your advice, and eventually it made my architectur even better :)

Comment: Hi again! Of course, I'm not saying you should always use a UINavigationController to handle your UIViewControllers on your apps. I just said that if you want to access to a instanced UINavigationBar from an instanced UIViewController you need an UINavigationController above. Anyway, thank you for your comment :)